# Cuál es la función de "-> index" en el siguiente código?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // greets with an index
    repeat(3) { index ->
        println("Hello with index $index")
    }
}
```

Soy nuevo en Kotlin, sé que la función repeat sirve a manera de bucle, pero no comprendo como funciona la instrucción:    `index ->`

Comment: ya leiste la [documentación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions)?

Comment: En la documentaciòn aparece eso, pero no indica que hace esa lìnea en especìfico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la descripción de la función `repeat` es clara:

> Executes the given function action specified number of times.
> A zero-based index of current iteration is passed as a parameter to action.

El segundo parámetro de `repeat` es la función que quieres ejecutar la cantidad de veces indicada. Esa función debe tener un parámetro de tipo `Int` para recibir el índice que `repeat` le va pasar como argumento.
"*zero-based index of current iteration*" significa que inicia en 0 e incrementa en 1 con cada iteración.

Este es un ejemplo de como pasarle una función existente. Funciona porque `printHelloIndex` tiene un parámetro de tipo `Int`. Si lo eliminas o agregas más parámetros, ocurrirá un error.

```
fun printHelloIndex(index: Int) {
    println("Hello $index")
}

repeat(3, ::printHelloIndex)
```

En tu ejemplo creas la función en el momento pero igualmente tendrá un parámetro de tipo `Int` y puedes darle un nombre. Tu lo llamaste `index` pero podría ser cualquier otro.

```
repeat(3) { i ->
    println("Hello with index $i")
}
```

Si no quieres darle un nombre puedes eliminar esa parte y acceder al agumento con la palabra `it`

```
repeat(3) {
    println("Hello with index $it")
}
```

Lo más importante que debes saber es que `repeat` no es una palabra reservada del lenguaje como `for` o `while` sino que es una función común que recibe como argumento a otra función. Puede ser confuso que un argumento esté fuera de los paréntesis pero eso es una feature de Kotlin llamada [trailing lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas).
Aunque esto también es válido

```
repeat(3, {
    println("Hello with index $it")
})
```

Si aún no te quedó claro tal vez te ayude ver su definición:

```
public inline fun repeat(times: Int, action: (Int) -> Unit) {
    for (index in 0 until times) {
        action(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!