# Function "sumado" is never used

Tags: android-studio, funciones, windows, kotlin, parametros

```
package com.example.taller_gua_kotlin

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import com.example.taller_gua_kotlin.R.layout.modulo02ejercicio9

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
    {
        private lateinit var Num1: EditText
        private lateinit var Num2: EditText
        private lateinit var Cal: EditText
        private lateinit var Mos: EditText

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(modulo02ejercicio9)

                Num1= findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber)
                Num2= findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber2)
                Cal= findViewById(R.id.Calcular)
                Mos= findViewById(R.id.mostrar)

            }
        fun Suma(a:Int,b:Int) :Int
            {
                return (a+b)
            }
        fun sumado(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")view: View)
            {
                val a:Int=Num1.text.toString().toInt()
                val b:Int=Num2.text.toString().toInt()
                val mos:Int=Suma(a,b)
                Mos.setText(mos.toString())
            }
    }
```

la función sumado no la toma por que? es para el instituto y tengo que presentar, y no me deja,
el error que me tira es "Function 'sumado' is never used.
Mi intento fue poner el que se ve ahi el @Suprise("UNUSED PARAMETER") y me sacó el tema de q view no se usaba, pero quedó el sumado sin funcionar y bueno me tira el error que anteriormente dije.
GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO!!

Comment: Eso no es un error, es una advertencia de que una función o parámetro nunca se usa. Deberías explicar lo que intentas hacer porque tu código no tiene mucho sentido.  Supongo que el ejercicio debe ser algo como sumar dos número al presionar un botón. Pero en tu código no se ve ningún botón o llamada a la función `sumado`. Es decir que, a menos que hayas configurado el click en XML, esa función nunca se va a ejecutar y por eso recibes la advertencia.

Comment: ahh entiendo la advertencia, mirá la idea es q ingreso dos números y aprieto en un boton y me da la suma (estoy aprendiendo recién kotlin jeje)

osea q me faltaría? como hago la llamada de la función? con un onclikListener?? no lo sé usar bien del todo todavia a eso.

Si querés te paso el código del layout.

Comment: en kotlin con `setOnClickListener { sumado(it) }` y en XML agregando el atributo `android:onClick="sumado` al botón. Si lo haces desde kotlin no necesitas que la función tenga el parámetro `view`

Comment: ahhh ahí estas diciendo q cuando hago click en el boton haga la suma y la muestre no?

el (it) que sería? es lo ultimo q pregunto jeje-.

Comment: Correcto. `it` en este caso es el botón que clickeaste. No puedo explicarlo bien en un comentario pero talvez [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453686/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-funci%C3%B3n-de-index-en-el-siguiente-c%C3%B3digo/453861) respuesta te ayude a entenderlo. Y recuerda que los comentarios no son para formular preguntas.

Comment: En Java y Kotlin si se manda llamar  la función mediante android:onClick="sumado" si se necesita el parametro view, ejemplo:  fun sumado(view: View) @AlanRomero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje que indicas :

> Function "sumado" is never used

es únicamente una advertencia, actualmente la IDE Android Studio indica que valores no tienen uso y se recomiendan eliminar.

en este caso puedes ver que el parámetro view no es usado dentro de la función, la única razón para agregar como parametro la vista es si llamas la función desde el layout mediante `android:onClick="sumado"`:

```
  fun sumado(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")view: View)
            {
                val a:Int=Num1.text.toString().toInt()
                val b:Int=Num2.text.toString().toInt()
                val mos:Int=Suma(a,b)
                Mos.setText(mos.toString())
            }
```

De otra forma si no estas llamando la función mediante `android:onClick`, aunque mandes llamar la función con el parámetro view este no será usado por lo tanto no es util, tu función debería ser únicamente:

```
  fun sumado()
            {
                val a:Int=Num1.text.toString().toInt()
                val b:Int=Num2.text.toString().toInt()
                val mos:Int=Suma(a,b)
                Mos.setText(mos.toString())
            }
```